# Object Array, retrieve data to text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a program that allows a user to type various data into 6 separate text boxes and then save it into an object called Book. Now I have done this easily but now i wish to be able to select the Book object in the listbox and populate the data back to the text boxes, i assumed it would be as easy as reversing the add to a degree but i have hit a roadblock.

Here is the primary part of my add button for context (I have commented it to hopefully clear up any variable names)

```
//use class book to create a new book 
Book addBook = new Book();
//use int.tryparse to convert the txtISBN to an int and store in the book object
bool parsed = int.TryParse(txtISBN.Text, out int isbn);
if (parsed)
{
    addBook.gsISBN = isbn;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid ISBN, Please enter an integer value");
    return;
}
//use double.tryparse to convert the txtPrice into a double and store in the book object
bool parse = double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out double price);
if (parsed)
{
    addBook.gsPrice = price;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Price, please enter a double value");
    return;
}
//use object addBook with the various getters and setters for 
//each variable and have them equal their textbox equivalent .
addBook.gsAuthor = txtAuthor.Text;
addBook.gsTitle = txtBookTitle.Text;
addBook.gsPublisher = txtPublisher.Text;
addBook.gsDate = txtDate.Text;
//myBooks( this is the Array)
myBooks[currentIndex] = addBook;
```

This above chunk of code works but then the below does not and is what i hope to figure out.

```
private void lstbook_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstbook.SelectedIndex == -1)//if there is no selected game output error message
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a book");
    }
    else
    {
        int index = lstbook.SelectedIndex;
        Book getBook = new Book();
        myBooks[currentIndex] = getBook;
        txtAuthor.Text = getBook.gsAuthor;
    }
}
```

Comment: The assignment is inverted: `getBook = myBooks[currentIndex];`. `currentIndex` is unknown, you shuld use the `lstbook.SelectedIndex`. You also should use a `List<Book>`, not an array and take a look at [DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings). The ListBox should contain items of type `Book`. The `MessageBox` message is controversial, a user cannot select a negative index, your code can.

Comment: Forgot to mention its part of an assignment for a course I am doing. I know its a bit silly how they get us to do it, but you gotta do what you gotta do. Also thanks that fixed my statement

Comment: How do you populate that `lstBook`?

Comment: I have a seperate display method that updates the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, it is easy. Lets say you have book array, assign this to `DataSource`

```
Book[] books = //.... retrieve books here
lstBooks.DisplayMember = "Name"; // Book.Name
lstBooks.ValueMember = "Isbn"; // Book.Isbn, but it is don't matter for our logic
lstBooks.DataSource = books; // in this order, please
```

Now, remember, all your books are there and you retrieve them using `lst.SelectedItem`. So, on `SelectedIndexChanged` do this:

```
// clear text boxes here first 
Book selectedBook = lstBooks.SelectedItem as Book;
if (selectedBook != null)
{
    txtIsbn.Text = selectedBook.Isbn;
    txtName.Text = selectedBook.Name;
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a book");
```

This can also be achieved using `BindingSource` where you bind all your controls and then you don't need manually populate your fields.